# Ask Ubuntu on mobile has an extremely large font size

Tags: bug, design, font

When using Ask Ubuntu on Android, the font is too large when it comes to anything except post content and comments.

I can reproduce the issue exists in Firefox and in Chrome.

The issue is exclusive to Ask Ubuntu (main site). All other sites in the SE network I tried, have a normal size font, even Ask Ubuntu Meta.

You can see the difference in font size in the below two screenshots (click for larger size).

[image: Main site]
[image: Meta site]

Comment: I can reproduce the difference between the two screenshots on my desktop Firefox, while simulating mobile view (Ctrl+Shift+M shortcut). I will take the positioning of the logo in the site header (center-aligned on the main site, and left-aligned on meta), as a clue, and suggest that the main site might have received an intended and purposeful style (CSS) update, while the meta site did not.

Comment: I get the same experience on Android - waiting a few days to see if it goes away.

Comment: [This is now fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391579/mobile-font-size-way-too-large#comment1310195_391582)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is supposedly a fixed bug: [Mobile font-size way too large](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391579/270345). But with caching involved, it may take a while to go away, and which sites you see it on is a matter of timing. I don't see the problem here on AU, but I do see it on Unix & Linux.

Comment: Ah thanks! Guess just need to wait it out for now as it seems to be a server side caching issue based on the answer to that question

Comment: Yep, I'm still having this problem on U&L. I guess they haven't figured out how to force this out of local caches?